# Classic ASP - Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Left'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Recently moved a classic ASP application from windows 2003 to windows 2008 R2. After a lot of work, everything is functioning the same except for one thing. On the search results and category pages, I get the following error when trying to go to the next page of results:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005'
Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Left'
/incpages/SearchResults.asp, line 1372
```

The code relative to this is here:

```
<form method="POST" name="MainForm" id="MainForm" action="/SearchResults.asp">

Page <input type="text" value="<%=ThisPageNum%>" size="3" name="Page" id="Page_SR" maxlength="4"> of <%=TotalPagesNum%>

<% Dim pageURL
pageURL = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL")
%>

<%If ((InStr(LCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL")),"/searchresults.asp")) > 0) Then%>

<%If ThisPageNum <> TotalPagesNum Then %>
                        <%If (ThisPageNum = "1") Then %>
                            <input type="image" border="0" name="btnNextPage" src="<%=SEOImage(Config_ImagesFolder & "/buttons/btn_nextpage.gif")%>" onClick="document.getElementById('Page_SR').value=<%=(ThisPageNum + 1)%>">
                        <%Else%>
                            <a href="<%Response.Write((Left(pageURL,(Len(pageURL)-1))) & ThisPageNum + 1)%>"><img src="<%=SEOImage(Config_ImagesFolder & "/buttons/btn_nextpage.gif")%>" border="0" name="btnNextPage" /></a>
                        <%End If %>
<%End If %>
</form>
```

So when I go here: /SearchResults.asp?cat=80&page=1 the results show up fine. If I go here: /SearchResults.asp?cat=80&page=2 or any other page within TotalPagesNum, I get that error.

I haven't been able to figure out why it stopped working after the switch

Comment: Just a hunch that `pageURL` is empty string so it errors on `-1` for second argument. What's the value of `pageURL` when on page 2?

Comment: You are right, it is empty on page 2. Damn.. so Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL") is not even grabbing the URL

Comment: Fixed it by just removing all that crap and doing simple if statements for the page number. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad my hunch is valid... :)